# Dagger 2 single instance of MyClass

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to refactor my code so I was thinking about Dagger2 to solve my issues. I've created `AppComponent` to store all of my `Singletons`:

```
@AppScope
@Component(
        modules = {
                AppModule.class,
                // more here...
        }
)
public interface AppComponent {

    Context exposeContext();

    CmdComponent newCmdComponent(CmdModule module);

    // ... few injections here
}
```

My `AppModule`:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Context context;

    public AppModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // ... provide appContext etc.

    @AppScope @Provides
    MyClass provideMyClass() {
        Log.i("DAGGER", "provideMyClass: ");
        return new MyClass();
    }

}
```

I inject this in my `Application` class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(app))
                .build();
    }

    public static AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

Then I have my subcomponent `CmdComponent` with different `@Scope`

```
@CmdScope
@Subcomponent(
        modules = {
                CmdModule.class
        }
)
public interface CmdComponent {
    void inject(Cmd cmd);
}
```

Now I'm injecting dependancies into my `Cmd` instance like:

```
@Inject MyClass myClass;

public Cmd() {
    App.getAppComponent()
            .newCmdComponent(new CmdModule())
            .inject(this);
}
```

Unfortunetly log: `Log.i("DAGGER", "provideMyClass: ");` and log inside `MyClass` constructor are shown multiple times... so I get new instance of `MyClass` every time. How to tell Dagger to give me the same instance (created once) every time?

Comment: Do you happen to be running crashlytics, chuck, or some other library that has their own process? I believe that their process creates a second `Application`, thus calling the constructor again. Your code itself looks fine

Comment: No. If I put log inside `Application` `onCreate` method it will pop only once

Comment: I'm not sure why it would make difference but have you tried component dependencies (instead of using `Subcomponent`)...using that here with pretty much same setup and app scope objects only created once.

Comment: Well, I tried and the result was the same. After that, I decided to create subcomponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I solve my issue. The solution is simple. My `AppScope` was created wrong. For some reason, I thought that annotation works like inheritance.

My custom annotation was like:

```
@Singleton
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AppScope {
}
```

and Dagger thought that my component is unscoped.. It should be like:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AppScope {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about the `.newCmdComponent(new CmdModule())`. Why do you do that, creating a new module every time? The component already has a module attached, you've set that on creation of the component.

Comment: They are using `AppScope` as their scope already, there is no need for `@Singleton`